# How to get the number of agents inside the node in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to get the number of pedestrian agents inside a polygonal node (e.g node1).

I applied the method getnumberofadmittedagents() on the text value,

node1.getnumberofadmittedagents()

but it maintained 0 even when the agents are inside the node.
Could you give me some advice on this matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, could you please add some code to your question?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I'm using node1.getnumberofadmittedagents() for the text value and it works after I adjusted node properties just as mentioned by Mr Felipe.

Answer (score 2):

To make this getnumberofadmittedagents() work, you need to use access restriction in the node, otherwise the method does nothing.

so in your node properties, just use acess restriction by condition and the condition is false always as follows:
[image: access]

Comment: beautiful, didn't know about this. Deleted my solution :)

Comment: yes, it's works. Thanks so much Mr Felipe and Mr Benjamin for the responses.